# How to simulate the driver's movement to check for live tracking

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, android-gps

Imagine I am building an app, let's say a pizza delivery app.

User Story: As a user, I want to track the movement of the delivery person against the map so that I can be ready to meet them when they are nearby

Let's say this app is already built, now I just need to test it. Obviously, telling my friend to install a driver's app and drive around so that I can see how well geofencing works is not the best approach here.

Are there any testing tools that allow me to simulate movement against google maps so that when I have a customer's app open I can test how well the live tracking of my driver works?

I tried googling it but didn't find anything, so what would you ladies and gentlemen use to simulate the movement to test the application?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any testing tools that allow me to simulate movement against google maps

Of course, there are. For Android, there is an app called [Lockito](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=en&gl=US). You can actually simulate the movement over a Google Map between two points.